# purgeIdleCellConnections: found one to purge conn

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using webservice connection in my application,its working on wifi network but changed data plan connection app was very slow,sometimes app was crash that time i got error was purgeIdleCellConnections: found one to purge conn = 0x1ddde360, how to solved this issuse? please help me.

By siva m

Answer (score 0):

The message you're seeing is an inadvertent debug message printed by some of Apple's network management code when it closes unused cell network connections. It is completely normal, and has nothing to do with your crash.

See: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1774/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40012992